# Filtering table in MySQL with difference between two timestamp columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in MySQL which includes the datetime columns `open_time` and `close_time`.

How can I select only rows in which `close_time` is at least one minute greater than `open_time`?

Comment: How are stored times (timestamp, string, ...)? If they are timestamp, you can something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE close_time>open_time+60`.

Comment: their column type as datetime in mysql structure. let me check for your solution @DavideVisentin

Comment: That works @DavideVisentin ... thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I edited the title of your question to succinctly summarize the problem you're having. I also cleaned up the grammar and removed the fluff to very directly state the problem — you want to select rows based on the difference between two columns. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit, datetime_expr1, datetime_expr2)` and something like

```
select * from MyTab T where TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,open_date,close_date) > 1
```

From docs

> TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit,datetime_expr1,datetime_expr2)
>
> Returns datetime_expr2 − datetime_expr1, where datetime_expr1 and
>   datetime_expr2 are date or datetime expressions. One expression may be
>   a date and the other a datetime; a date value is treated as a datetime
>   having the time part '00:00:00' where necessary. The unit for the
>   result (an integer) is given by the unit argument. The legal values
>   for unit are the same as those listed in the description of the
>   TIMESTAMPADD() function.
>
> mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,'2003-02-01','2003-05-01'); -> 3
>   mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,'2002-05-01','2001-01-01');  -> -1
>   mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'2003-02-01','2003-05-01 12:05:55'); -> 128885
>
> Note The order of the date or datetime arguments for this function is
>   the opposite of that used with the TIMESTAMP() function when invoked with 2 arguments.

Comment: hai tamil, can i have your official gmail id or facebook id.??

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,close_time,open_time) > 60
```

More info: 
http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timestampdiff-function.php